# Asymptotic density and sums of subsequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, asymptotics

In some recreational mathematics I was doing I encountered the following infinite sum: $$\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{7}+...$$
At a glance, the terms in this sum resemble the harmonic series, $1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},...$

My intuition told me that the above sum diverges, and a little bit of rigor shows that this is indeed the case. This led me to thinking about the idea of [asymptotic density](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density). The sequence $\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{5},\frac{1}{7}...$ should have an asymptotic density of $1/2$ within the harmonic numbers, so it seems reasonable that its sum should diverge. So, I wanted to frame this question in a more general way. Suppose we have a real sequence $a:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{R} \ ; \ a:n \mapsto a(n)$ and let its sequence of partial sums be $s(n)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a(k)$. For now, we'll assume $s(n)$ is does **not** converge. Now lets consider an infinite subsequence of $a$ which I'll call $a'$, which is the image of the set of natural numbers $M=\{m_1,m_2,m_3,...\}$ (where $\forall k, m_{k+1}>m_k$.) under the function $a$. I.e, $a'(k)=a(m_k).$ **Is it true** that if the set $M$ has a *nonzero* asymptotic density in $\mathbb{N}$, that the sequence of partial sums $s'(n)$ of the subsequence $a'$ will *also* be divergent? Or better: If $s(n)$ *does* converge, If the set $M$ has an asymptotic density of $0$ in $\mathbb{N}$, does $s'(n)$ necessarily converge? I've been trying to think of some sort of counterexample to either or these statemments and have not yet found one. This is an area of mathematics I do not know much about (I'm an undergraduate applied and computational mathematics student) but I am quite curious about it. Any hints that might lead me in the direction of a proof, or a neat counterexample, would be very very nice.

EDIT: To summarize, I am interested if the sum of any subsequence of density **zero** in a sequence with a *convergent* sum will also **con**verge, or if the sum of any subsequence of **nonzero** density in a sequence with a *divergent* sum will also **di**verge.

EDIT 2: The user @bof produced a nice counterexample to the above. But as user @GReyes mentioned, what if we require $a(n)$ to be decreasing? Are both these ideas perhaps true in that case?

Comment: This seems to me an interesting question. I understand you call asymptotic density something like $\lim_{k\to\infty} k/m_k$? This reminds me of the Cauchy condensation test. You can probably prove what you want using the same idea.

Comment: You’re going to want to impose some restrictions on $a$. If $a(n)=1$ for all $n$, for instance, then the sequence of partial sums of any subsequence, no matter how sparse, will diverge.

Comment: @bof: Given the comment that its asymptotic density should be $\frac12$, I think that the OP is looking at the sequence of $\frac1{2n+1}$ for $n\ge 1$.

Comment: @bof Sorry, my wording was unclear. I meant the sequence of reciprocals of odd numbers. So the sequence continues $\frac{1}{9},\frac{1}{11},$ etc.

Comment: You mean, the sequence of reciprocals of odd numbers greater than one. OK.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott my question already addressed this, since the partial sums of $1,1,1,...$ are divergent. My question pertained to the convergence of sums of subsequences with density zero in sequences with *convergent* sums.

Comment: I'll edit the question so it's more clear.

Comment: @K.defaoite: I was going by what you wrote: ‘For now, we'll assume $s(n)$ is does **not** converge.’

Comment: @Brian M. Scott "if $s(n)$ does converge, and $M$ has density $0$ in $\mathbb{N}$ does $s'(n)$ necessarily converge?" Later in the question.

Comment: Isn't the divergent series $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1{\lfloor n\ln n\rfloor}$$ a density zero subseries of the harmonic series?

Comment: @bof I'm aware these sort of things exist. However, I was interested if any subsequence of *nonzero* density in sequence with a divergent sum will *also* always diverge.

Comment: @Kdefaoite Can you please explain what you mean by density/asymptotic density of a subsequence?

Comment: The divergent series $$1+0+\frac12+0+\frac13+0+\cdots$$ has a convergent subseries $$0+0+0+\cdots$$ of density $\frac12$. If you don't like the $0$ terms, consider instead the divergent series $$1+1+\frac12+\frac14+\frac13+\frac19+\frac14+\frac1{16}+\cdots$$

Comment: @GReyes Sure. I'm fairly new to this sort of mathematics so please excuse the slight lack of rigor. Suppose we take the first $N$ natural numbers. Define $M_N$ as the set of numbers less than $N$ that belong to the set $M$ referenced in the question. Then I am concerned with the limit $$\lim_{N \to \infty}\frac{\#M_N}{N}$$ Where $\#$ denotes cardinality.

Comment: Ok, thanks. That is more or less what I had in mind in my first comment. I have the impression that what you assert is true if you assume that the sequence is monotonic decreasing.

Comment: @bof This is truly a marvelous counterexample. Thank you.

Comment: @GReyes This is a nice point, and would discount bof 's counterexample. I'll add that matter of curiosity to post.

Comment: The divergent series $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1{\lfloor n\ln n\rfloor}$$ is also a density zero subseries of the **convergent** series $$1-1+\frac12-\frac12+\frac13-\frac13+\cdots$$

Comment: Look up Schlomich's test  https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiLsNORsdrpAhXnHjQIHbx2BA0QygQwAHoECAMQCA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FCauchy_condensation_test%23Schl%25C3%25B6milch%27s_Generalization&usg=AOvVaw3yK3-f-AAd5agZ-OmzvDMJ

Comment: It applies to positive decreasing sequences. Your example with odd terms in the harmonic series is a particular case.

Comment: @GReyes Thank you for the reference. I'll have a look into this. I'm not sure how the information in the Wikipedia page relates to subsequences, but after a bit of thought I should be able to get a grasp on it. Amazing work!